# Animating Custom Bottom Navigation Tab Bar using React Navigation & Reanimated 2

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have this Custom React Native Bottom Navigation Component built with :

- **@react-navigation/bottom-tabs**
- **react-native-reanimated**

Basically I want it to have scale animation whenever the tab goes in / out focus.

Video demonstration here :
https://imgur.com/a/t1IqrbZ

as you can see currently it only animates when the tab is being focused, meanwhile the previous tab did not animate at all

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BottomTabBarButtonProps, createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Gap from 'components/Gap';

//File Import
import HomeScreen from 'screens/home/HomeScreen';
import CategoryHomeScreen from 'screens/category/CategoryHomeScreen';
import VolunteerHomeScreen from 'screens/volunteer/VolunteerHomeScreen';
import ProfileHomeScreen from 'screens/profile/ProfileHomeScreen';

//Utils Import
import { CATEGORY_HOME, HOME, PROFILE_HOME, VOLUNTEER_HOME } from 'utils/routesConstant';
import useTheme from 'utils/hooks/useTheme';
import { IcCategory, IcHome, IcProfile, IcVolunteer } from 'assets/icons';
import { RootStackParams } from 'utils/routes';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

interface CustomTabBar extends BottomTabBarButtonProps{
    name: string;
    title: string;
    component: ({ route, navigation }: NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParams, any>) => React.JSX.Element;
    icon: (focused?: boolean) => React.JSX.Element;
} 

const MainBottomNavigation = () => {
    const {Colors,Fonts} = useTheme();
    const intl = useIntl();

    const tabBarStyle:ViewStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom:24,
        left:16,
        right:16,
        borderRadius:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        height: 64,
        elevation:1,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        shadowColor: Colors.dropShadow,
        backgroundColor:Colors.white
    }
    const TabArray = [
        {
            id:1,
            name:HOME,
            title:intl.formatMessage({defaultMessage:"Home"}),
            component:HomeScreen,
            icon:(focused?:boolean) => (
                <IcHome stroke={focused ? Colors.primary : Colors.textPrimary} width={24} height={24}/>
            )
        }, ....
    ]

    const CustomTabBar = (props:CustomTabBar) => {
        const scale = useSharedValue(1.0);
        const focused = props.accessibilityState?.selected
        const {onPress} = props
        const targetScale = focused ? 1.2 : 1.0;
        //This only animates when tab is focoused in, when I navigate out from the tab it instantly goes to original size without animating.
        scale.value = withSpring(targetScale, {
            damping: 10,
            stiffness: 800,
        });
        const tabMenuStyleAnimated = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            return {
                transform: [{ scale: scale.value }],
            };
        });
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} style={[{top:10,flex:1,alignItems:'center'}]} onPress={onPress}>
                <Animated.View style={tabMenuStyleAnimated}>
                {props.icon(focused)}
                </Animated.View>
                <Gap height={4} />
                <Text style={[Fonts.fontMedium, Fonts.sizeXS, focused ? Fonts.textMainColor : Fonts.textPrimary,Fonts.textCenter]}>{props.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName={HOME}
            screenOptions={{ 
                headerShown: false ,
                tabBarShowLabel:false,
                tabBarStyle
            }}>
                {TabArray.map((item,_)=>(
                    <Tab.Screen 
                        key={item.id} 
                        name={item.title as any} 
                        component={item.component}
                        options={{
                            tabBarButton:(props)=><CustomTabBar {...props} title={item.title} component={item.component} icon={item.icon} name={item.name}/>
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

export default MainBottomNavigation;
```

Any idea of what I'm missing ?

Comment: Do you want to create a "bobble" animation (scales up and immediately down again) like in the video or shall the icon stay big as long as the tab is active and you want to animate properly between the scale states?

Comment: Thanks for your time, sorry my original post isn't clear enough.

What I want is that when I changed tab it should also "bobble out" (scales up and immediately down again ), from the videos it only "bobble in" and the exiting animation is not working.

Comment: Have you tried moving the ```withSpring``` declaration inside of a useEffect function with the focused prop as entry in the dependency array?

Comment: Yeah I tried it but didn't work